# Integrating HP Fortify on TeamCity with Maven project MojoExecutor error

Tags: maven, teamcity, fortify

We're trying to integrate HP Fortify scan on our TeamCity for our maven projects. There are three steps: Clean, translate and scan.

For the translate step, we keep getting the error:

*Failed to execute goal com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:sca-maven-plugin:4.20:translate (default-cli) on project Cirrus.Parent: Execution default-cli of goal com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:sca-maven-plugin:4.20:translate failed: A required class was missing while executing com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:sca-maven-plugin:4.20:translate: org/twdata/maven/mojoexecutor/MojoExecutor*

I've added the dependency in the pom file like this (tried multiple versions):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>mojo-executor</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```